# Mutually recursive types in Python 3.6, using named tuple syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement Nodes and Edges for a graph. Here is my code:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class Node(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    edges: List[Edge]

class Edge(NamedTuple):
    src: Node
    dest: Node
```

This raises an error because the `Edge` type is not defined when `Node` is created.

```
NameError: name 'Edge' is not defined
```

Switching the definitions around doesn't work because `Edge` also refers to `Node`.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6):

Use string literals.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class Node(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    edges: List['Edge']

class Edge(NamedTuple):
    src: Node
    dest: Node
```

The details are in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), under the "Forward References" section:

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

Answer (score 5):

You can use string literals; they'll be evaluated later:

```
class Node(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    edges: List['Edge']
```

See the [*Forward References* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) of PEP 484 -- Type Hints:

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

For `NamedTuple` objects, forward references are stored explicitly for later dereferencing:

```
>>> Node._field_types
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'edges': typing.List[_ForwardRef('Edge')]}
```

which a type checker can later dereference from the locals and globals:

```
>>> typing._eval_type(Node._field_types['edges'], globals(), locals())
typing.List[__main__.Edge]
```